# VCO Tuning with MOSCAPs

Tags: rf, integrated-circuit, pll, cadence, vco

I'm designing an integrated VCO for use in an FM Radio frequency PLL. In order to reduce the external part count, I had the idea of using MOSCAPs as the frequency tuning element instead of external varactors. My circuit is given below:

My basic topology is a Colpitts oscillator, with NM0 as the gain device, L0/M0/M1 forming the tank, and M2/M3 as my tuning elements. "vfb" is the tuning voltage, the feedback from the phase detector (i.e. the input to the VCO).

[image]

This curve shows the capacitance of my MOSCAPs as a function of bias voltage. The Y-axis is in amps because of the way my testbench is set up --- just imagine it's fF instead of fA. M0 and M1 are both reverse-biased to around -0.5V, while M2 and M3 are biased based on vfb.

[image]

And here are my results, from a transient simulation for various values of vfb.

[image]

**My Question:** How much do I need to be concerned by the significant ripple I see in the last figure? And are there any ways I can try to mitigate it in design? Or was my MOSCAP idea flawed from the start? (Note: I did introduce some noise in the simulation in order to get the oscillator to start up.)

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not an expert, but it might be helpful to look into different performance characteristics for VCOs e.g. phase noise and stability and try to compare it to other published designs or your specification. Also, why don't you use MOS varactors instead of MOS capacitors? The two are quite similar but MOS varactors might be suited better for VCOs?

Comment: IMO a MOS varactor is a special use case for a MOSCAP. What do you think the difference between the two is?

Comment: A MOS capacitor is a MOS transistor with source and drain connected together. A MOS varactor is not a transistor but looks like an NMOS with an n-well. Also the C-V curves are different. If you have access to the book RF-Microelectronics by Razavi, take a look at the varactor section.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at that book! I'm not sure the PDK I'm using has a simulation model for varactors, but I suppose I could try to work around that.